# Disable SSH BusyBox

Tags: linux, ssh, dropbear

I'm connecting to a BusyBox and I'm trying to disable the ssh dropbear service. Can someone help me for closing the port access or stop the service. The SO is Linux with kernel 2.6.32.33

Thankyou

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what kind of a system you're logging into.

**CAREFUL**: you may cut yourself off from the device if you're connecting via SSH, proceed with care.

But in general you can try `/etc/init.d/dropbear stop` (you may want to double check if this is the proper script name in your distro, I'm not sure if it's common everywhere). Now if this will only stop the service and if get disconnected an you need it enabled back, you can restart the device.

Other safety measures can include using anacron, leaving a sleeping start command (f.e. `sleep 5m; /etc/init.d/dropbear start`) in `screen` or `tmux`, etc.

To make it permanent do `update-rc.d dropbear disable` after stopping and ensuring that everything works as intended.